# Can amulets or trinkets (jewelry) be created by the blacksmith, jewelcrafter, or another artisan?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I visit the blacksmith, I can create (or learn to create) any type of weapon or armor, except for amulets and rings.

If I visit the jewelcrafter, I can create any type of gems.

**Does a artisan exist where I can create my own amulets and rings?**

At the moment I don't see any, but are there plans that you can find/purchase for either artisan that will allow you to create these items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the early Beta, the Jewelcrafter was supposed to be able to create jewelry, but in the live version, this is not the case. Here is a list of what Covetous Shen is capable of [crafting](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/). So in short, **no, you can't** in Diablo 3.

Comment: Certainly puts a premium price on good amulets and rings then.

Thanks for the link, didn't know that existed - here's the Blacksmith one as well: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe

Comment: Yep, its pretty much the exact same thing as diablo 2, in which they made it so amulets and rings were worth looking for, and so that they had more of a value instead of just crafting one :D